# Dialogflow 'conv.followup()' not sending to followup intent from webhooks

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

My "Default Welcome Intent" sends the user to a followup intent called "Main Intent"

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', async (conv) => {
    conv.followup('Main Intent', {})
});
```

However when I test it on the Actions on Google simulator, I always get sent back to the "Default Fallback Intent"

To make sure to see if the "Main Intent" gets triggered, I have added a simple response:
[image: intent response]

However I never get the response "Main Intent executed!"

Those are my intents:

[image: Dialogflow Intents list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter for `conv.followup()` shouldn't be the *name* of the Intent you want to trigger. It should be an *event* that you have an Intent set to respond to. So you are saying that you want to trigger the "Main Intent" event, and you likely don't have an Intent set for this event.

However... there are very few actual uses for `followup()`. If you want to send back different replies in your Intent based on some condition - just send back those different replies from your fulfillment webhook. There is no need to redirect to a different Intent to handle it.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem as Leonard. Unfortunately I correctly insert the event name rather than the intent name. The behaviour seems more frequent on the Android Google Assistant app, while on iOS it works correctly. Is it a Google bug?

Comment: It isn't clear from your description, but seems unlikely. I suggest you create a new question illustrating your problems with as much detail as you can including the code you're using, screen shots of the details of all the Intents in question, examples (both text and screen shots) that show what is and what should be happening, and any error logs you have. The more information you can provide the better our chances are of being able to help you track down the problem.